# trying to have a horizontal scroll view dynamic pictures

Tags: android, image, dynamic, horizontalscrollview, android-volley

I am trying to make an android app with Volley that can pull in as many images as I want then set them in a horizontal scroll view.  So far I have them coming in but no matter what I do it won't let me make it scroll.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/containerLayout" >

    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:id="@+id/scrollLayout">

       <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/niv_large"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java file

```
public class AppActivity extends Activity
{

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    Button button;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        imageLoader =  new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new DiskBitmapCache(getCacheDir(), 0));
//        final ImageView networkimage = ImageView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.niv_large));

//        imageLoader.get("http://files.vividscreen.com/soft/b0d52a794a2f44f1a208d1fdf6088125/The-Dark-Knight-Batman-768x1280th.jpg", ImageLoader.getImageListener(networkimage, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher));

        ArrayList<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

        imageUrls.add( "http://images.cpcache.com/merchandise/514_400x400_Peel.jpg?region=name:FrontCenter,id:28298128,w:16" );
        imageUrls.add( "http://images.cpcache.com/merchandise/514_400x400_NoPeel.jpg?region=name:FrontCenter,id:25042524,w:16" );
        imageUrls.add( "http://michaelkonik.com/wp-content/uploads/2006/06/2014-World-Cup-Logo-400x400.jpg" );
        //imageUrls.add( "http://hdwallsize.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Barcelona-Wallpaper-HD-Lionel-Messi.jpg" );
        //add other image urls as above until done

        LinearLayout containerLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);



        setContentView( containerLayout, lParams);         

        for( int i = 0; i < imageUrls.size(); i++ )
        {
            ImageView image = new ImageView( this );

            //Log.e( "Checking image stuffs for null",  "Image= " + image + " url=" + imageUrls.get(i) + "imageLoader=" + ImageLoader.getImageListener( image, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher) );
            imageLoader.get( imageUrls.get( i ), ImageLoader.getImageListener( image, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher) );
            containerLayout.addView( image  );
        }        
                                                                              // icon loading, icon error
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/containerLayout" >

    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:id="@+id/scrollLayout">
       <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/containerlLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </HorizontalScrollView> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

use xml and add all images to container layout which has id "containerLayout"
setContentView(main.xml) will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly not working with the XML layout file, since you never load it. You provide your own LinearLayout instead of supplying the XML layout. That's why you can't scroll.

1. Remove the LinearLayout you instantiate and make a reference from it to R.id.myContainer
2. Replace `setContentView( containerLayout, lParams);` with `setContentView( R.layout.your_xml);`

You don't have to include the parameters when using an XML layout file.

The solution:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/containerLayout" >

    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:id="@+id/scrollLayout">

       <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:id="@+id/myContainer" />

    </HorizontalScrollView> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java

```
public class AppActivity extends Activity
{

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    Button button;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        imageLoader =  new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new DiskBitmapCache(getCacheDir(), 0));
//        final ImageView networkimage = ImageView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.niv_large));

//        imageLoader.get("http://files.vividscreen.com/soft/b0d52a794a2f44f1a208d1fdf6088125/The-Dark-Knight-Batman-768x1280th.jpg", ImageLoader.getImageListener(networkimage, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher));

        ArrayList<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

        imageUrls.add( "http://images.cpcache.com/merchandise/514_400x400_Peel.jpg?region=name:FrontCenter,id:28298128,w:16" );
        imageUrls.add( "http://images.cpcache.com/merchandise/514_400x400_NoPeel.jpg?region=name:FrontCenter,id:25042524,w:16" );
        imageUrls.add( "http://michaelkonik.com/wp-content/uploads/2006/06/2014-World-Cup-Logo-400x400.jpg" );
        //imageUrls.add( "http://hdwallsize.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Barcelona-Wallpaper-HD-Lionel-Messi.jpg" );
        //add other image urls as above until done

        // Get a reference to the LinearLayout inside the HorizontalScrollView
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myContainer);

        // Replaced container with R.layout.your_xml where 'your_xml' refers to your XML file. Parameters are also not needed since they are as attributes in the XML tag
        setContentView( R.layout.your_xml);         

        for( int i = 0; i < imageUrls.size(); i++ )
        {
            ImageView image = new ImageView( this );

            //Log.e( "Checking image stuffs for null",  "Image= " + image + " url=" + imageUrls.get(i) + "imageLoader=" + ImageLoader.getImageListener( image, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher) );
            imageLoader.get( imageUrls.get( i ), ImageLoader.getImageListener( image, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher) );

            // Add the view to myContainer using the referece
            myContainer.addView( image );

            //containerLayout.addView( image  );
        }        

        // icon loading, icon error
    }
}
```

Comment: LinearLayout myContainer = findViewById(R.id.myContainer);  this line is throwing me an error saying cannot convert from View to LinearLayout

Comment: That is correct, you should cast it to a LinearLayout. I forgot to include that. I'll edit the answer.